# Private Static Readonly Field Capitalization

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Pascal or camel case?

I name private fields and private static fields using camel case. I name consts (as suggested by MS naming conventions) with pascal case (regardless of private vs. public)....

So what about private static readonly? Logic says camel case...but a private static readonly is functionally like a const...right?

Comment: Why you think it's like a const ?

Comment: Because, in usage, private static readonly is the same as a cosnt: set once, can't change, static scope. I realize const has a completely different implementation (being compiled and interpreted and whatnot).

Comment: No, it isn't like a const:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4577372/618649

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> **Do use Pascal casing in field names**...
>
> The naming guidelines for fields **apply to static public** and protected fields. You should not define public or protected instance fields.

[MSDN Names of Type Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229059.aspx)

> Read-only static field  =  Pascal

[MSDN Official Naming Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)

**General Rules:**

> Do use **Pascal** casing for **all public**
>   member, type, and namespace names
>   consisting of multiple words.
>
> Note that this rule does not apply to
>   instance fields. For reasons that are
>   detailed in the Member Design
>   Guidelines, **you should not use public
>   instance fields.**
>
> Do use **camel casing** for parameter
>   names.

**Full List:**

```
IDENTIFIER             CASE        EXAMPLE
----------------------+-----------+---------------
Class                  Pascal      AppDomain 
Enumeration types      Pascal      ErrorLevel 
Enumeration values     Pascal      FatalError 
Event                  Pascal      ValueChanged 
Exception class        Pascal      WebException 
Read-only static field Pascal      RedValue 
Interface              Pascal      IDisposable 
Method                 Pascal      ToString 
Namespace              Pascal      System.Drawing 
Parameter              Camel       typeName 
Property               Pascal      BackColor
```

[MSDN Official Naming Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)

Also consider

- [MSDN Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)
- [MSDN General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx)

Comment: This list does not cover *private* members or non-read-only-and-static fields at all.

Comment: This list says the opposite.  The only one listed here that has an obviously restricted scope is *parameter*.  Which is why it is Camel.  the link takes you to "Capitalization Conventions" which does mention that Pascal applies to *public* members.

Comment: @cdhowie: Good point and I have updated my answer to cover public and static fields.

Comment: Field Naming conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta31s3bc(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I've got a private static read-only field + public getter for it. Not sure what to do, the names clash by this convention (and the convention offered by default on ReSharper).

Comment: So what's the straightforward answer? Should the first letter of a private static readonly field be capitalized or not?

Answer (score 14):

I got a warning in StyleCop for:

```
    private readonly Color LabelBackColor = Color.Black;
```

*Warning 364 SA1306 : CSharp.Naming : Variable names and private field names must start with a lower-case letter: LabelBackColor.*

See [this discussion](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/6872): private readonly fields should start with a lower case character. This means Camel case.

Comment: The question is about private _static_ readonly fields, not instance fields.

Comment: StyleCop recommends that static readonly fields start with an uppercase letter, according to [this rule](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/blob/master/Project/Docs/Rules/SA1311.html) on their GitHub page.

Answer (score 9):

No, `private static readonly` is not in and of itself like `const` at all.  Consider:

```
private static readonly IList<int> foo = new List<int>();
```

You can still do `foo.Add(0);`.  Such fields are only const-like when the object itself, as well as any referenced objects, are immutable.

Comment: But you can't reassign the value of a private static readonly...So are you of the opinion to use camel case for private static readonly?

Comment: Not according to StyleCop (SA1311 static readonly fields must begin with upper-case letter).

Comment: @sotn Thankfully, we live in a universe where we have free will and don't have to follow arbitrary style rules that don't make any sense.

Comment: @cdhowie Not my universe. Arbitrary or not, following style rules to the letter (whether you like/don't like some rules in it) help standardization of the code and it's maintenance.

Comment: @sotn If the decision has been made for you, sure. However, this particular style rule doesn't make any sense on the face of it (making a private field look like a public field is the opposite of helpful) and I would strongly advocate against using it wherever one has the power to do so.

Comment: @sotn: Then how should a public static property be named that returns the value of a private static readonly field?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper According to StyleCop, it should be the same. Although I'm not sure whether the Analyzer package of StyleCop behaves like that or it's really that illogical rule. I'm annoyed by this one and couldn't help myself suppress the warnings for private ones and use lower case all the time..

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example reference source. Interestingly Microsoft here used underscore for private fields and camelCase (no underscore) for private static readonly http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,3e3f6715773d6643. But this second example also shows, Microsoft doesn't have its own standard for field naming : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about matching anyone else's conventions -- as long as you're consistent with whatever naming convention you use it doesn't really matter what you choose to do.  There are far more important things to worry about.

Comment: It's convenient to have other people make these decisions for you though, since they're fairly inconsequential.

Comment: It's important to follow standard conventions. Imagine if you move to a new project, and have to learn to conform to conventions which are alien to you. Imagine trying to incorporate a third party library that has conventions contrary to your project's conventions. Imagine a new hire coming in and trying to cope with your internal proprietary convention standards. I have to completely disagree with this answer - **On the contrary, it is VERY important follow a standardized set of conventions accepted by the industry.** Don't reinvent the wheel because you are too lazy to look up the right way.

Comment: Standard conventions are kind of a myth.